# get rid of spaces in a vector and then connect in R

Tags: r

I have a vector which is the dimnames of another object (let's call it `obj`) in R:

```
"I(PT(z))"     "trt"          "I(PT(z)):trt"
```

I am not sure how many spaces are there in this output. Now I want to have a resultant vector of `"I(PT(z))"+"trt"+"I(PT(z)):trt"`, i.e., replace the space with "+" signs. The tricky part here is that, `length(obj)=3`, and `obj[[1]]` gives `"I(PT(z))"`, and so on. Is there a convenient way to do the concatenation? Thanks.

Comment: You want to keep `"` in the output or just `"I(PT(z))+trt+I(PT(z)):trt"`? Also, you don't have spaces there. You have a vector, so nothing to replace, rather just to concatenate into a single value? Also, why are you using `[[`, do you have a list there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- c("I(PT(z))", "trt", "I(PT(z)):trt")
x
[1] "I(PT(z))"     "trt"          "I(PT(z)):trt"

paste(x, collapse="+")
[1] "I(PT(z))+trt+I(PT(z)):trt"
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the desired output so I would wait until you get some clarifications from the OP instead of trying to be the fastest gun in the west.

Comment: Seemed like a pretty straightforward question to me, though it is possible I missed something.

Comment: I appreciate your points, but you can make them without the insults.

Comment: There were no insults here. The "fastest gun in the west" is the official SO termonology for such a bahaviour.  Google it up. And flagging my comments is very infintile btw.

Comment: I did not flag either of your comments.  Someone else must have done that, unless I clicked something by accident.  I genuinely appreciate the info, and sincerely apologize if I have offended you or anyone on this site.